# Apache Kafka + Kafka not deleted data with 0 size - is it reasonable?

Tags: linux, apache-kafka

We have a 5 nodes Kafka cluster , while Kafka version is 3.5

in `server.properties` we set to retain logs up to 48 hours and the other configuration set as the following

```
retention.ms=345600000 ( 48H) 
retention.bytes=107374182400
log.segment.bytes=1073741824   - Default:   1073741824 (1 gibibyte)
```

before I explain the issue I want to explain the meaning of `retention.ms`

`log.retention.(ms/minutes/hours)` The amount of time a log can be stored before Kafka marks the partition for deletion. The default value is one week.

so far is clear .... but on many topic partitions we seen the following:

lets see one of the partition in some topic , and by `ls -ltr` we can see how **old** the data files in folder

```
ls -ltr
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka       43 Jan  9 16:21 partition.metadata
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka       10 Feb  5 02:14 00000000000000000214.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka        0 Feb  5 02:14 00000000000000000214.log   <-- file is zero size
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka       10 Feb  5 02:14 leader-epoch-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka 10485756 Feb  5 02:19 00000000000000000214.timeindex
```

from above we can see the data file - `00000000000000000214.log` is from Feb 5 , when today is 13/2/2024

but on other hand we can see that file - `00000000000000000214.log` size is 0

so is it make sense that Kafka not delete the old data files that with size 0?

or maybe its bug in apache Kafka version ?

more info about Kafka files:

```
The .log file is an actual segment containing records up to a specific offset. The name of the file defines the starting offset of the records in that log.
The .index file contains an index that maps a logical offset (in effect the record’s id) to the byte offset of the record within the .log file. It is used for accessing records at specified offsets in the log without having to scan the whole .log file.
The .timeindex file is another index used for accessing records by timestamp in the log.
The .snapshot file contains a snapshot of the producer state regarding sequence IDs used to avoid duplicate records. It is used when, after a new leader is elected, the preferred one comes back and needs such a state in order to become leader again.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka will keep unclosed segments (closed after `log.segment.bytes` in size). If you've produced less, or nothing, to a topic, then you'll likely have empty segment files that'll be kept longer than the specified retention time